# Why it doesn't work after I set requirepass password in redis?

Tags: redis

I want to set a password in Redis. First I modified the configuration file of Redis. Remove '#' in front of requirepass foobared. And set requirepass kingredis.
I restarted Redis.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server restart
```

But it doesn't work.

```
hadoop@master:~$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set b "sss"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> auth kingredis
(error) ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
```

My Ubuntu is 14.04.

Comment: Try `SHUTDOWN` from the cli - it is possible that your `/etc/init.d/redis-server` service is not managing the actual server process that you connect to. Alternatively, it is possible that you're not editing the correct .conf file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH PASSWORD
(error) ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET requirepass "mypass"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH mypass
Ok
```